XML Placement Problem with xml.etree.ElementTree
I'm using Python's xml.etree.ElementTree to generate XML, and I’m encountering an issue where an XML subelement appears under a different tag than intended.
My function looks like this:
def generate_product (parentElement, products: dict):
    for product_id, product_detail in products.items():
        product = ET.SubElement(parentElement, "PRODUCT")

        supplier_pid = ET.SubElement(product, "SUPPLIER_PID")
        supplier_pid.text = product_detail["supplier_pid"]

        product_details = ET.SubElement(product, "PRODUCT_DETAILS")

        description_short = ET.SubElement(product_details, "DESCRIPTION_SHORT")
        description_short.text = product_detail["description_short"]
        ean = ET.SubElement(product_details, "EAN")
        ean.text = product_detail["ean"]
        manufacturer_pid = ET.SubElement(product_details, "MANUFACTURER_PID")
        manufacturer_pid.text = product_detail["manufacturer_pid"]
        manufacturer_name = ET.SubElement(product_details, "MANUFACTURER_NAME")
        manufacturer_name.text = product_detail["manufacturer_name"]
        delivery_time = ET.SubElement(product_details, "DELIVERY_TIME")
        delivery_time.text = product_detail["delivery_time"]

        product_features = ET.SubElement(product, "PRODUCT_FEATURES")

        reference_feature_system_name = ET.SubElement(product_features, "REFERENCE_FEATURE_SYSTEM_NAME")
        reference_feature_system_name.text = product_detail["reference_feature_system_name"]
        reference_feature_group_id = ET.SubElement(product_features, "REFERENCE_FEATURE_GROUP_ID")
        reference_feature_group_id.text = product_detail["reference_feature_group_id"]

        product_order_details = ET.SubElement(product, "PRODUCT_ORDER_DETAILS")

        order_unit = ET.SubElement(product_order_details, "ORDER_UNIT")
        order_unit.text = product_detail["order_unit"]
        price_quantity = ET.SubElement(product_order_details, "PRICE_QUANTITY")
        price_quantity.text = product_detail["price_quantity"]
        quantity_min = ET.SubElement(product_order_details, "QUANTITY_MIN")
        quantity_min.text = product_detail["quantity_min"]
        quantity_interval = ET.SubElement(product_order_details, "QUANTITY_INTERVAL")
        quantity_interval.text = product_detail["quantity_interval"]

        product_price_details = ET.SubElement(product, "PRODUCT_PRICE_DETAILS")

        product_price_details_start_datetime = ET.SubElement(product_price_details, "DATETIME", attrib={"type":"valid_start_date"})

        price_start_date = ET.SubElement(product_price_details_start_datetime, "DATE")
        price_start_date.text = product_detail["valid_start_date"]

        product_price_details_end_datetime = ET.SubElement(product_price_details, "DATETIME", attrib={"type":"valid_end_date"})

        price_end_date = ET.SubElement(product_price_details_end_datetime, "DATE")
        price_end_date.text = product_detail["valid_end_date"]

        if product_detail["daily_price"] == "TRUE":
            daily_price = ET.SubElement(product_price_details, "DAILY_PRICE")
            daily_price.text = "true"

        product_price = ET.SubElement(product_price_details, "PRODUCT_PRICE", attrib={"price_type":f"{product_detail['price_type']}"})

        price_amount = ET.SubElement(product_price, "PRICE_AMOUNT")
        price_amount.text = product_detail["price_amount"]
        price_currency = ET.SubElement(product_price, "PRICE_CURRENCY")
        price_currency.text = product_detail["price_currency"]
        tax = ET.SubElement(product_price, "TAX")
        tax.text = product_detail["tax"]

        mime_info = ET.SubElement(product, "MIME_INFO")

        mime = ET.SubElement(mime_info, "MIME")

        mime_type = ET.SubElement(mime, "MIME_TYPE")
        mime_type.text = product_detail["mime_type"]
        mime_source = ET.SubElement(mime, "MIME_SOURCE")
        mime_source.text = product_detail["mime_source"]
        mime_descr = ET.SubElement(mime, "MIME_DESCR")
        mime_descr.text = product_detail["mime_descr"]
        mime_purpose = ET.SubElement(mime, "MIME_PURPOSE")
        mime_purpose.text = product_detail["mime_purpose"]
        mime_order = ET.SubElement(mime, "MIME_ORDER")
        mime_order.text = product_detail["mime_order"]

And the placement problem happens at this place in the code:
        product_price_details = ET.SubElement(product, "PRODUCT_PRICE_DETAILS")

        product_price_details_start_datetime = ET.SubElement(product_price_details, "DATETIME", attrib={"type":"valid_start_date"})

        price_start_date = ET.SubElement(product_price_details_start_datetime, "DATE")
        price_start_date.text = product_detail["valid_start_date"]

        product_price_details_end_datetime = ET.SubElement(product_price_details, "DATETIME", attrib={"type":"valid_end_date"})

        price_end_date = ET.SubElement(product_price_details_end_datetime, "DATE")
        price_end_date.text = product_detail["valid_end_date"]

        if product_detail["daily_price"] == "TRUE":
            daily_price = ET.SubElement(product_price_details, "DAILY_PRICE")
            daily_price.text = "true"

When I run this code, the DAILY_PRICE element ends up inside the DATETIME element with type valid_end_date, instead of being placed directly under PRODUCT_PRICE_DETAILS.
      <PRODUCT_PRICE_DETAILS>
        <DATETIME type="valid_start_date">
          <DATE>2024-08-14</DATE>
        </DATETIME>
        <DATETIME type="valid_end_date">
          <DATE>2024-09-30</DATE>
          <DAILY_PRICE>TRUE</DAILY_PRICE>
        </DATETIME>
     </PRODUCT_PRICE_DETAILS>

How can I ensure that DAILY_PRICE is correctly placed directly under PRODUCT_PRICE_DETAILS and not inside DATETIME?

We need to execute your code to be able to help you. Learn about minimal reproducible example and why it is required.

Change the order, like:
product_price_details = ET.SubElement(product, "PRODUCT_PRICE_DETAILS")

if product_detail["daily_price"] == "TRUE":
    daily_price = ET.SubElement(product_price_details, "DAILY_PRICE")
    daily_price.text = "true"

product_price_details_start_datetime = ET.SubElement(product_price_details, "DATETIME", attrib={"type":"valid_start_date"})

price_start_date = ET.SubElement(product_price_details_start_datetime, "DATE")
price_start_date.text = product_detail["valid_start_date"]

product_price_details_end_datetime = ET.SubElement(product_price_details, "DATETIME", attrib={"type":"valid_end_date"})

price_end_date = ET.SubElement(product_price_details_end_datetime, "DATE")
price_end_date.text = product_detail["valid_end_date"]

product_price = ET.SubElement(product_price_details, "PRODUCT_PRICE", attrib={"price_type":f"{product_detail['price_type']}"})

Output:
<PRODUCT_PRICE_DETAILS>
    <DAILY_PRICE>true</DAILY_PRICE>
    <DATETIME type="valid_start_date">
      <DATE>2024</DATE>
    </DATETIME>
    <DATETIME type="valid_end_date">
      <DATE>2025</DATE>
    </DATETIME>
    <PRODUCT_PRICE price_type="EURO" />
</PRODUCT_PRICE_DETAILS>

